# Generating a JWT within Power BI using Power Query

Tags: oauth, jwt, powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to retrieve an OAuth token by making a call to a Rest API. I have been successfully able to do so using a power query function like below:

```
let

GetJson = Web.Contents("https://my-oauth-provider/adfs/oauth2/token",
[
Headers = [#"Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"],
Content = Text.ToBinary("client_id=service@example.com&client_assertion=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtp...&grant_type=client_credentials&client_assertion_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer&resource=urn://gaurav")
]
),
FormatAsJson = Json.Document(GetJson),
#"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(FormatAsJson),
access_token = #"Converted to Table"{0}[Value]
in
access_token
```

However, one of the parameter that we pass to OAuth Rest API is client assertion that in itself is a JWT token that needs to be generated on the host machine.

At the moment, I generate this client assertion token using a C# utility however we do not wish to ship this utility to our clients. Rather, if a user has installed the necessary certificate on his machine, I want to write a Power query function that can read that certificate and generate me a JWT token with the required claims in it.

What I am trying to do looks something in Postman like:

[image: Postman call to get oauth token]

In simpler words, I am trying to generate a JWT within Power Query function.

Comment: Read through this, to see if your case is an exception that will allow a secure OAuth2 query without a custom connector

https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2021/08/29/connecting-to-rest-apis-with-oauth2-authentication-in-power-query-power-bi/

Comment: Thanks for your response. The article also mentions that achieving the above using M Code in power BI is a bad practice. I haven't used Custom connectors and do not have enough power BI knowledge. If the above is possible using custom connectors, please let me know.
Regards!